# `derivingUnbox` doesn't work for types with more than 6 Ints

Tags: debugging, haskell

This program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving

data Node = Node Int Int Int Int Int Int Int deriving (Show)
derivingUnbox "Node"
    [t| Node -> (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) |]
    [| \ (Node a b c d e f g) -> (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) |]
    [| \ (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) -> Node a b c d e f g |]

main = print 7
```

Fails to compile, with this error message:

```
debox_error.hs:6:1:
    No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                       Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                       (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicLength’
    In the expression: Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicLength vec_a320
    In an equation for ‘basicLength’:
        basicLength (V_Node vec_a320)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicLength vec_a320
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeFreeze’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeFreeze :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                      Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable
                                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                                        (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m)
                                        Node
                                      -> m (Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node)
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeFreeze mvec_a31Y)’
    In the expression:
      (V_Node
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeFreeze mvec_a31Y))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeFreeze’:
        basicUnsafeFreeze (MV_Node mvec_a31Y)
          = (V_Node
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeFreeze mvec_a31Y))

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeThaw’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeThaw :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                    Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node
                                    -> m (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable
                                            Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                                            (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m)
                                            Node)
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeThaw vec_a320)’
    In the expression:
      (MV_Node
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeThaw vec_a320))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeThaw’:
        basicUnsafeThaw (V_Node vec_a320)
          = (MV_Node
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeThaw vec_a320))

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeIndexM’
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeIndexM :: Monad m =>
                                      Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node -> Int -> m Node
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeIndexM vec_a320 idx_a31W)’
    In the expression:
      ((\ (a_a328, b_a329, c_a32a, d_a32b, e_a32c, f_a32d, g_a32e)
          -> Node a_a328 b_a329 c_a32a d_a32b e_a32c f_a32d g_a32e)
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeIndexM vec_a320 idx_a31W))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeIndexM’:
        basicUnsafeIndexM (V_Node vec_a320) idx_a31W
          = ((\ (a_a328, b_a329, c_a32a, d_a32b, e_a32c, f_a32d, g_a32e)
                -> Node a_a328 b_a329 c_a32a d_a32b e_a32c f_a32d g_a32e)
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeIndexM vec_a320 idx_a31W))

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeCopy’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeCopy :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                    Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable
                                      Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m)
                                      Node
                                    -> Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node -> m ()
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeCopy mvec_a31Y vec_a320
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeCopy’:
        basicUnsafeCopy (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) (V_Node vec_a320)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Base.basicUnsafeCopy mvec_a31Y vec_a320
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                       Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                       (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.elemseq’
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Base.elemseq
        vec_a320
        (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
           -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
           val_a32f)
    In an equation for ‘elemseq’:
        elemseq (V_Node vec_a320) val_a32f
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Base.elemseq
              vec_a320
              (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
                 -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
                 val_a32f)
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                       Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                       (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicLength’
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicLength mvec_a31Y
    In an equation for ‘basicLength’:
        basicLength (MV_Node mvec_a31Y)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicLength mvec_a31Y
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                       Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                       (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeSlice’
    In the first argument of ‘MV_Node’, namely
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeSlice
         idx_a31W len_a31X mvec_a31Y’
    In the expression:
      MV_Node
        (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeSlice
           idx_a31W len_a31X mvec_a31Y)
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeSlice’:
        basicUnsafeSlice idx_a31W len_a31X (MV_Node mvec_a31Y)
          = MV_Node
              (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeSlice
                 idx_a31W len_a31X mvec_a31Y)

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                       Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                       (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicOverlaps’
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicOverlaps mvec_a31Y mvec'_a31Z
    In an equation for ‘basicOverlaps’:
        basicOverlaps (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) (MV_Node mvec'_a31Z)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicOverlaps mvec_a31Y mvec'_a31Z
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeNew’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeNew :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                   Int
                                   -> m (Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                           (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node)
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeNew len_a31X)’
    In the expression:
      (MV_Node
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeNew len_a31X))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeNew’:
        basicUnsafeNew len_a31X
          = (MV_Node
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeNew len_a31X))

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeReplicate’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeReplicate :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                         Int
                                         -> Node
                                         -> m (Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                                 (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node)
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeReplicate
          len_a31X
          (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
             -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
             val_a32f))’
    In the expression:
      (MV_Node
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeReplicate
            len_a31X
            (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
               -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
               val_a32f)))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeReplicate’:
        basicUnsafeReplicate len_a31X val_a32f
          = (MV_Node
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeReplicate
                  len_a31X
                  (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
                     -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
                     val_a32f)))

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeRead’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeRead :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                    Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                    -> Int -> m Node
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeRead mvec_a31Y idx_a31W)’
    In the expression:
      ((\ (a_a328, b_a329, c_a32a, d_a32b, e_a32c, f_a32d, g_a32e)
          -> Node a_a328 b_a329 c_a32a d_a32b e_a32c f_a32d g_a32e)
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeRead mvec_a31Y idx_a31W))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeRead’:
        basicUnsafeRead (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) idx_a31W
          = ((\ (a_a328, b_a329, c_a32a, d_a32b, e_a32c, f_a32d, g_a32e)
                -> Node a_a328 b_a329 c_a32a d_a32b e_a32c f_a32d g_a32e)
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeRead mvec_a31Y idx_a31W))

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeWrite’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeWrite :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                     Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                       (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                     -> Int -> Node -> m ()
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeWrite
        mvec_a31Y
        idx_a31W
        (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
           -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
           val_a32f)
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeWrite’:
        basicUnsafeWrite (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) idx_a31W val_a32f
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeWrite
              mvec_a31Y
              idx_a31W
              (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
                 -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
                 val_a32f)
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicClear’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicClear :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                               Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                 (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                               -> m ()
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the expression: Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicClear mvec_a31Y
    In an equation for ‘basicClear’:
        basicClear (MV_Node mvec_a31Y)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicClear mvec_a31Y
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicSet’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicSet :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                             Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                               (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                             -> Node -> m ()
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicSet
        mvec_a31Y
        (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
           -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
           val_a32f)
    In an equation for ‘basicSet’:
        basicSet (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) val_a32f
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicSet
              mvec_a31Y
              (\ (Node a_a321 b_a322 c_a323 d_a324 e_a325 f_a326 g_a327)
                 -> (a_a321, b_a322, c_a323, d_a324, e_a325, f_a326, g_a327)
                 val_a32f)
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeCopy’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeCopy :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                    Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                    -> Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                         (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                    -> m ()
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeCopy mvec_a31Y mvec'_a31Z
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeCopy’:
        basicUnsafeCopy (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) (MV_Node mvec'_a31Z)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeCopy mvec_a31Y mvec'_a31Z
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeMove’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeMove :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                    Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                    -> Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                         (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                    -> m ()
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the expression:
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeMove mvec_a31Y mvec'_a31Z
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeMove’:
        basicUnsafeMove (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) (MV_Node mvec'_a31Z)
          = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeMove mvec_a31Y mvec'_a31Z
    In the instance declaration for
      ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
         Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector Node’

debox_error.hs:6:1:
    Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector
                        Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                        (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int))
      arising from a use of ‘Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeGrow’
    from the context (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 basicUnsafeGrow :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m =>
                                    Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node
                                    -> Int
                                    -> m (Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.MVector
                                            (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Node)
      at debox_error.hs:(6,1)-(9,49)
    In the second argument of ‘Control.Monad.liftM’, namely
      ‘(Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeGrow mvec_a31Y len_a31X)’
    In the expression:
      (MV_Node
       `Control.Monad.liftM`
         (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeGrow mvec_a31Y len_a31X))
    In an equation for ‘basicUnsafeGrow’:
        basicUnsafeGrow (MV_Node mvec_a31Y) len_a31X
          = (MV_Node
             `Control.Monad.liftM`
               (Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.basicUnsafeGrow mvec_a31Y len_a31X))
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you nest an unboxed type inside another unboxed type?  So you could have a `Node3 Int Int Int` with `Node7 Node3 Node3 Int`.  I've never used that functionality so I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: The problem (it seems) is that Haskell doesn't recognize the 7-tuple as Unbox (?), so it wouldn't really help how I organize the ints on the original type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is because under the hood the `vector-th-unbox` library converts your data type with N fields into an N-tuple and then uses the `Unbox` instance provided by the `vector` library for N-tuples.  The reason this fails for 7-tuples is that the `vector` library only provides instances up to 6-tuples.

The fix is to either:

(A) Update the `vector-th-unbox` library to not use the tuple intermediate workaround to derive `Unbox` instances and instead just derive the `Unbox` instance directly or:

(B) Add `Unbox` instances for larger tuples to the `vector` library

Solution (A) is the better solution in the long run.